# Binary cloud Mask from MODIS (MOD35_L2) using MRTSWATH

Tags: modis, hdf, modis-reprojection-tool

When the MRTSwath tool is fed with MOD35_L2 cloud mask HDF file, the tool provides six tif images (b0 till b5). Each tif file has 8 bit information.
Are these 6 images somehow indicating the 48 bits (https://modis-images.gsfc.nasa.gov/_docs/CMUSERSGUIDE.pdf) in MODIS cloud mask?

I am intersted only in the first 3 bits of the 48 bit mask. I need only the pixels which are 'cloudy' and 'uncertain clear'.

I have extracted the binary cloud mask using LDOPE 1.7 (by parsing bits 0-2==001 OR 0-2==101 ,Cloud_Mask SDS). The resulting HDF  file was fed to MRTSwath. But the mask derived like this looks too cloudy for my purpose.

syntax:

create_mask -of=output.hdf -on=255 -off=0
 -mask="input.hdf,Cloud_Mask,0-2==001,OR,input.hdf,Cloud_Mask,0-2==001"

Is there any alternate way to create a mask from the 6 tif images (MRTSwath)?